# c# mysql connectionstring question

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, connection-string

Im working in c#, I'm using mysql .net connector to interact with a remote mysql db. Is it safe to include the connection string inside the code and work with the db directly through the command object or should I be posting to a php middle layer to hide the connection string?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion:

1. You shouldn't put Your connection
   string directly in Your C# code if
   Your application could be
   decompiled = I mean WinForms application.
2. If You are working on a Windows
   application, then try to implement a
   log-in window. Where user will pass
   his/her user name and password. This
   solution needs a mysql user or users
   for every person that would have
   access to the system.
3. If Your are working on a web
   application, then put You connection
   string inside web.config file.
4. If You are working on application
   with unrestricted access, then I
   think You should implement some
   layer... but remember, never pass
   SQL queries as plain text via
   network, as someone could sniff it.
   I would recommend some kind of
   webservice.

Comment: its a winform application.. 1 part of my app implements a mysql message cue where queries to the database are made frequently, say ever 2 seconds, would the php layer slow this down would you say?

Comment: I would say, security first! As in everyday life.... every agent/broker/intermediary increases costs (time in this case). If Your query executes fast (faster then 2 seconds) then I think it's fine - maybe some kind of queue or semaphore should be implemented.

Answer (score 1):

Then the connection string is just stored in the PHP middleware layer, so what's the difference?  It has to be stored somewhere.

I would keep it simple and store it in the app.config or web.config of the C# app your writing.

Couple notes about storing it:
 - Production connection strings should not be stored in version control.
 - A production configuration file should exist on the production servers with the connection string.
 - For added security, you can encrypt your connection string ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/89211k9b(v=vs.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/89211k9b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx))

Comment: the difference is that the connectionstring will always be invisible since the php code is not public(?) from what I can reason any http analyzer could grab the connection string as its sent out from a to b, or is that incorrect?